# MVC Kendo Grid ClientTemplate string not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I'm trying to make this work but I don't understand what's wrong with this template string.

```
"#=" + column.ColumnName + "# #if(NumeroGermi != \"0\" && #=" + column.ColumnName + "# == \"Positivo\") {# <a href=\"javascript: JavascriptFunction(); \" aria-hidden=\"true\" id=\"settings\"><span class=\"fa fa-cog\">&nbsp;</span></a> #} #"
```

I've noticed that the bit that doesn't make it work is the second if condition.
This way it will work, but i still need the second condition:

```
"#=" + column.ColumnName + "# #if(NumeroGermi != \"0\") {# <a href=\"javascript: JavascriptFunction(); \" aria-hidden=\"true\" id=\"settings\"><span class=\"fa fa-cog\">&nbsp;</span></a> #} #"
```

Comment: Adding logic to your templates is very difficult to maintain. Try to approach with readonly properties, since you are using mvc, to move your logic to your compiled code before it is read by your kendo grid. The difference by doing so is that you will simply #= kendo.toString(yourObject, "C") # and what not without requiring logic.

Comment: Please can show us how you apply the template on the grid and what error do you get ? (eg: Invalid template or the output is not what  excpected)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

`"#=" + column.ColumnName + "# # if(NumeroGermi != \"0\" && " + column.ColumnName + " == \"Positivo\") { # <a href=\"javascript: JavascriptFunction(); \" aria-hidden=\"true\" id=\"settings\"><span class=\"fa fa-cog\">&nbsp;</span></a> # } #"`

I don't believe you need the encapsulation for the second condition.